Can Rare Crop affect Boons that are already common?
The Rare Crop Boon from Demeter randomly selects Boons to make them common then upgrades the rarity every few encounters. Can Rare Crop affect Boons that are already common?

Yes, when you receive the Rare Crop Boon, it selects a few of your existing Boons and sets them to common if they are of higher rarity.
Therefore, whether a Boon is common or of higher rarity, Rare Crop will begin its upgrade process either by setting it to common first (if it’s of higher rarity) or starting from common directly (if it’s already common).
